# Constrained extension of generic object does not match type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, class-extensions

I am trying to make an extension to a generic class which is constrained by the type of the generic. This is a simplification of the code I believe should work:

```
struct Thing<T> {
    var value: T
}

struct ContainsStringThing {
    var stringThing: Thing<String>
}

extension Thing where T == String {                           // <-- Error location
    func containedStringThing() -> ContainsStringThing {
        return ContainsStringThing(stringThing: value)
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Same-type requirement makes generic Parameter 'T' non-generic

I searched for a way to fix this and found a suggestion to use a protocol to constrain the extension instead of a type: [link to article](https://medium.com/snips-ai/generic-type-extension-by-retrofitting-protocols-in-swift-2-c8fe194d757c#.tiiys2eh3). After doing that I ended up with this:

```
protocol StringProtocol { }

struct Thing<T> {
    var value: T
}

struct ContainsStringThing {
    var stringThing: Thing<StringProtocol>
}

extension Thing where T: StringProtocol {
    func containedStringThing() -> ContainsStringThing {
        return ContainsStringThing(stringThing: self)         // <-- Error location
    }
}
```

Now it does let me constrain the extension but it shows a different error message:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Thing<T>' to expected argument type 'Thing<StringProtocol>'

Basically now it knows that `T` conforms to protocol `StringProtocol` by itself, but it doesn't know it when referring to the whole object `Thing<T>`.

is there any workaround to this or should I submit it as an evolution proposal to the swift mailing list?

Note: All the code is tested on a playground, you can just copy and paste it to try it.

Comment: The problem with your second code is that T does not conform to StringProtocol.  It can't, because you have _no_ types that conform to StringProtocol! (A protocol is not a first-class type and cannot conform to itself.)

Comment: The constrained extension should be declaring internally that T conforms to StringProtocol (in this instance). This means that you could assign T to anything that expects a type conforming to StringProtocol. By the same logic the type of the object which is Thing<T> should also be equivalent to Thing<StringProtocol>, there is enough information to infer this.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a new instance of Thing with the value from self.

```
extension Thing where T: StringProtocol {
    func containedStringThing() -> ContainsStringThing {
        return ContainsStringThing(stringThing: Thing<StringProtocol>(value: self.value))
    }
}
```

In Swift 2.2 such extension constraint means that **containedStringThing()** function will be available for instance of Thing whose value type conforms to StringProtocol.

Would be nice if Swift compiler could infer type of **self.value** as **StringProtocol**. In such case you could just write 
`ContainsStringThing(stringThing: self)` instead of 
`ContainsStringThing(stringThing: Thing<StringProtocol>(value: self.value))`. You should definitely fill a proposal.

Comment: Sadly this wouldn't work for me. As I said in the post this is a simplification of the problem, the Thing object is a lot more complex and just transferring the internal value itself would not be enough.